# express secret key length

Tags: security, node.js, session, express, sha256

Are there any recommendations for the length of the secret key used to cryptographically hash session data in connect/express? I see everything from 60+ character strings to the canonical 'keyboard cat'.

For my immediate use case, I intend to use SSL for the entire site and the payoff for a brute-force attack is medium to low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the longer the better, but making it 60+ is a bit overkill. If the key is a random string ( which it should be ), then do you realize how many combinations you can get with 60 characters? A lot. :)

Comment: Indeed. However, the key gets fed into a sha256 hash function. Is the cryptographic strength of that hash improved greatly if I go from an 8 character input to a 16 character input? What about 32? Is it linear? Does it matter? I don't know.

Comment: The strength increases exponentially, because number of combinations increases exponentially. So brute force/dictionary attacks become useless probably already after using 10 characters. Make it 20 to be sure. :)

Comment: Haha, yeah that makes sense. In searching for an answer I ran across several handy-wavy suggestions, but if the only way to get at the data is a brute force attack then ~20 characters certainly does provide a crazy-pants number of combinations. :)